# HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed

Tags: asp-classic

i just moved from my old host to Godaddy, which seems to be a worst web host with no support.

i moved my asp website (written in classic asp) to the new godaddy windows hosting. but when i run the site i get the below error

> HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed

this site worked perfectly with my previous host.

below is what i have in my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

can someone tell me why am i getting that error and how can i fix it?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this will help - [Run Classic ASP pages with IIS7](http://piyush-chawhan.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/run-classic-asp-pages-with-iis7.html) suggestion is the `<section name="asp" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />` should be `<section name="asp" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />` in the `%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\applicationHost.config` config file which if you're on shared hosting I doubt you'll have access to. Sounds like GoDaddy might not be supporting Classic ASP by default.

Comment: Actually came across this recently myself, it occurs after renaming a website. The fix is to stop and start the associated Application Pool so it is aware of the website name change, until you do you will get this error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue moving a website from one hosting account (classic windows) to another (plesk), both on GoDaddy. After much headache troubleshooting, I managed to fix it by removing the whole `<asp>` tag from the web.config file;

```
    <!-- <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/> -->
```

IIS 8 (only option in plesk) does not support this option altogether and configuring detailed error messaging is done differently using:

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

You can find further instructions on this [GoDaddy support page](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3430/getting-detailed-errors-on-your-windows-website?countrysite=ca)

Comment: Before using this suggestion, consider recycling the application pool or restart iis service as described in the other answer and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 12):

I just encountered the same error this morning after renaming some Websites in IIS. A restart of IIS got my sites up and running again in seconds. Presumably the .config files are read on startup and 'likely' the cause of this error for me.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had changed the names of my sites to their actual domain.com, and that is what did it. But the strange thing is only one site was not affected by this change? Go figure. Thank you so much.

Comment: To add a brick on the wall, just had the same problem, and restarting the Application Pool is enough

Comment: Easy enough to replicate in IIS (tested in 8.5 anyway). Create a website, view the default page (or set one up). Rename the site (under the 'Sites' tree-view) in Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager, and try to browse the site again (right click on site > Manage Website > Browse). If you followed steps like that at any stage, you might have received: **HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed**. The answer: ```Restart IIS```. Or as @iguypouf suggests STOP the associated Application Pool, and START it again (may involve: Error 0x80070425 prompt, click OK, Start again) or revert rename.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be allowed to use the  tag.

This configuration is found on the IIS applicationHost.config file:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config
```

Open your editor as administrator and set the value below to Allow instead of Deny. This section might be in the beginning of the file.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
      <secion name="asp" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
      (...)
      </section>
    </sectionGroup>
  <configSection>
<configuration>
```

If you don't have access to the applicationHost.config file, ask the support at GoDaddy or the administrator wherever it is to do this for you.